# Poll applet download progress in jnlp with applet descriptor and in javascript

Tags: javascript, applet, loading, progress, jnlp

I have a WebStart applet that I deploy using the deployJava script. The jnlp file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<jnlp codebase="" href="launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
    <information>
        <title>someApp</title>
        <vendor>someCompany</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://www.someCompanysWebsite.net"/>
        <description>someDescription</description>
        <description kind="short">someShortDescription</description>
    <offline-allowed/>
    </information>
<update check="background"/>
<security>
<all-permissions/>
</security>
    <resources>
<j2se version="1.5+"/>
<jar href="mainJar.jar" main="true"/>


<jar href="lib1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib2.jar"/>
<jar href="lib3.jar"/>
<jar href="platform.jar"/>
<jar href="plugin.jar"/>
<jar href="slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar"/>
<jar href="slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar"/>
</resources>
    <applet-desc height="1" main-class="com.companyName.applet.appletClass" name="appletName" width="1">

    </applet-desc>
</jnlp>
```

As you can see, my applet is 1x1 in size, so I don't want to display anything with it. It just serves to expose some java methods to javascript. So, if I make a javascript call, for example

```
//javascript code
var applet = document.getElementById('appletName');
```

I get a valid handle to the applet and I am able to call its methods in javascript like this:

```
 //javascript code
    applet.doStuff();
```

Of course, every applet has the isActive() method defined, so in my javascript code I can check like this if the applet is fully loaded:

```
    //javascript code
    function isFullyLoaded()
    {
      if ( !applet.isActive() ){
         setTimeout('isFullyLoaded()',1000);
      }
      else 
      {
         //do nice stuff requiring the applet is loaded
      }
    }
```

However, as the loading of the applet might take a while, I would like to have a progress indication of its loading. A quick look at Sun (or Oracle, if you are so inclined) shows this:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/customProgressIndicatorForApplet.html

However, this implies that I want to show a loading bar or anything when the applet loads. I dislike applet appearance and that is why I just want to poll applet loading with javascript, like that on some interval:

```
//javascript code
alert(applet.getLoadingProgress());
```

What should I do and should I change jnlp declaration or anything like that. Any pointers or comments would be appreciated. Note that I don't want a custom progress bar, but just a structure so that I can poll progress with javascript during loading.

Cheers.

Edit:
@amol
I will bring to your attention that JNLP deployed applets and application, during their loading, call a generic DownloadServiceListener class's method progress(java.net.URL url, java.lang.String version, long readSoFar, long total, int overallPercent) whenever one of the jars required is downloaded. Knowing the total numbers of jars and the number of jars yet to be downloaded will serve as a perfect progress indicatior. I want also to bring to your attention that if you debug the JNLP deployment, you will see these methods being called and logging as network level events. So, my question is how to get a hang of these methods using javascript so i can have some estimate about progress as I don't want the user to look at java console to estimate progress. I don't want to also show an indeterminate progress loader, as it is a breeze to implement that, but no practical use whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure how to *poll* as such, but the approach I have used in the past to achieve what you are describing is as follows -

- When you load the applet (In my case
  I usually insert relevant html in the
  DOM on click of a button or
  something), display your
  javascript/html specific loading
  indicator.
- When applet loads, it calls back a
  javascript method. JS now knows that the applet is fully loaded, takes down the loading indicator and does any further JS->applet communication, etc.

(Display a determinate progress bar is not possible using this approach. But a a generic loading indicator that masks over the entire html body or an indeterminate progress bar is very much possible and breeze to implement)

Answer (score 3):

In the documentation from the Oracle site which you posted (http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/customProgressIndicatorForApplet.html), the applet calls the function below to indicate its progress, which then updates the Applet UI and the progress bar accordingly.

```
public void progress(URL url, String version, long readSoFar,
                 long total, int overallPercent) {        
  // check progress of download and update display
  updateProgressUI(overallPercent);

}
```

I believe, you can simply, replace the call to `updateProgressUI(overallPercent)`, with some call to a Javascript function which updates a progress indicator in the web page.

Test this and let us know if it is possible.

Comment: I would test it, thank you. I wanted to avoid having to call my javascript from Java (I wanted to do it the other way around) but maybe a JSObject will be the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

> I dislike applet appearance ..

Change it using the ['image' attribute](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/special_attributes.html#specialattributes).

Comment: The question, of course, is about how to poll applet web-start deployed applet's progress with javascript and not how to make a custom loading screen or replace the default graphic with a custom one.

Comment: There are many ways to achieve the end goal and this looks like at least a valid option. If the option does not work for the OP, OP should not accept this as the correct answer but I am not sure why it was downvoted. +1 @ Andrew Thompson.

Comment: It was, of course, downvoted, because it is not an anwer to the question at all. The question is: 'HOW to get progress of a JNLP deployed applet using javascript', not 'HOW to change applet appearance' or 'How to use custom loader'. Therefore, the answer is irrelevant as it is an answer to a completely different question.

Comment: I had other semi-formed ideas on how to approach this in the event that a cycling image of an indeterminate progress bar was not enough.  Given your comment, I could not be bothered giving them further thought.  Good luck with it!